# Exposing wep app functions in the global - aye or nay?

Tags: javascript, security

As you know, web applications often use JavaScript to attach functions to DOM elements so that user can interact with the application.

However, I was surprised that some web applications expose these functions in the global space so that I can execute them in the browser console. Is this considered vulnearable and a bad practice?

For example, by using these exposed functions, I may be able to create a script and run it in the console to do some creative things that were not expected to happen.

For this reason, should I always strive to conceal access to my web applications in the console as much as possible? It seems obvious that I should, but I may be wrong as I am still very new to web development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is primarily an opinion-based question and probably not well-suited to SO's format. But I want to answer, so I'll answer with a CW.

The primary reason for avoiding creating globals isn't security or privacy for your code. Your client-side JavaScript code is public knowledge. Anyone who wants to know what your code does can find out, just by downloading your scripts and looking at them. Even if you obfuscate your scripts, there are good un-obfuscators that can help make them readable again. Google's Closure Compiler, particularly with advanced settings, makes that *really* difficult, but most of what you're doing can be understood.

No, the primary reason for not creating more globals is that the global namespace is already ***really*** crowded, and so creating more globals exposes you to the risk of conflicts between yours and other scripts you may want to include. The global namespace is particularly crowded on browsers, because browsers dump all kinds of things into it, including properties for every element that has an `id` (the property name is the `id`, the value is the element, on most browsers).

Best practice is to not expose any globals **at all**. If you *have* to have globals, have just one, which is an object you put anything you need on.

Comment: Thanks, so you are saying that judging security from whether some functions are exposed in the global is irrelevant because js is visible to anyone in the first place. So to prevent attacks from some bad users, I just need to code js carefully and do not let any unexpected attacks happen.

Comment: @CookieMonster: Pretty much. Everything that comes in from the client browser has to be treated as suspect.